# How to webscrape from Marketwatch Financials for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from **MarketWatch**. I have a formula to pull from Finviz:

=value(regexextract(query(importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$C7,"table",9),"select Col2 where Col1 = 'Income' ",0),"[-\d.]+"))

*Note*: The C7 box contains SBSW.

How do I scrape the *Sales/Revenue of 2021 for the ticker SBSW*. Here's the link:
**https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/SBSW/financials**

The result should show **172.19**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using this formula, and it works for me:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/SBSW/financials", "//*[@id='maincontent']/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div/span")
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

You can get the xpath_query with the developer tools like this:

[image]

**Edit answer, removing the B at the end**

#### First option

If the letter is always "B."

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/SBSW/financials", "//*[@id='maincontent']/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div/span"),"B","")
```

#### Second option

If the letter at the end always changes.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/SBSW/financials", "//*[@id='maincontent']/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div/span"),"[0-9]+.+[0-9]")
```

**Reference:**

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Is there a way to remove the B and M? I have a new code in case it helps!

Comment: =value( 
  regexextract( 
    regexreplace( 
      regexreplace( 
        query( 
          importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & $C7, "table", 9), 
          "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Income' ", 0 
        ), 
        "B", "e9" 
      ), 
      "M", "e6" 
    ), 
    "[-\d.e]+" 
  ) 
)

Comment: @wheresjohnnywalker, I edited the answer with some options to remove the B.

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to pick the next number down I copy down the XPath by right-clicking and inspecting, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.